# How to generate heat map (kernel map) from polygon geometries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, heat-map

I have a polygon type shapefile with the total number of reptiles in 7 regions of my city, I would like to generate a heat map (kernel map) from this shapefile.

QGIS only generates heatmaps from point-type shapefile data. Is it possible to generate from polygons?

shapefile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AFIXvV0fAHSp06we4-eiiBK93wLz4P-g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The very principle of heatmaps is based on points. You could convert your polygons to points (e.g. centroids) - but polygons are not apt for heatmaps. You should reconsider what you want to visualize and how. Where did you get the idea of a heatmap from? Why do you think this is a good way to visualize your data? Just because it looks nice?